# prove that SVM chooses the bisecting line of nearest support vectors?

Tags: svm, proof, convex

I have trouble solving the problem 3.18 from "pattern recognition" by "Sergios Theodoridis, ‎Konstantinos Koutroumbas"
the problem is :

Show that for the case of two linearly separable classes the hyperplane obtained as the
SVM solution is the same as that bisecting the segment joining two closest points
between the convex hulls of the classes.

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paper that shows the relationship between SVM and convex hull is

[www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~cvrg/bennett00duality.pdf](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~cvrg/bennett00duality.pdf)

I don't know if the proof you ask is there, but the picture of separable data and convex hull is there - the intuition becomes clear after reading the beginning of the paper.